# Переменные значения у присылаемого JSON

Tags: java, json, парсер, jackson

Присылается либо пустой массив, если значения нет, либо строка, как указать jacksonу проверку типа перед парсингом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это русский StackOverflow и задавать вопросы здесь нужно на русском языке.

Comment: Может это поможет https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization Раздел 3 Custom Deserializer